# Expose interface from an ASMX web service

Tags: c#, web-services, interface, asmx

I'm working on an old project that has ASMX web services. The consumer client uses this web service as a web reference. This all works fine except that the web service doesn't expose any interfaces, only concrete classes.

I added an interface to one of the asmx web services, but it seems like that the interface isn't available when I update my web reference on the client app.

Is it even possible to expose an interface from ASMX web services?

Comment: refer "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581356/why-cant-i-expose-an-interface-in-a-net-asmx-web-service".

Comment: @kumarch1 I found that topic as well. But I'm not sure what to think of it. He says: `WCF can't serialize an interface either`. But WCF **can** expose interfaces. So I'm not sure what he's talking about. I'm simply looking for a similar solution for ASMX.