# interface in webservice

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, client

Can I use such webservice:

```
[WebMethod]
public void SetFieldValue(IFieldValue fieldValue, long itemId)
{
    fieldValue.SetValue(itemId);
}
```

Where IFieldValue is an interface?
if so - how can I determine the instance type in the client?
if I cannot use this in webservice, should I create 4 different webservices that does the same (I have 4 implements of IFieldValue)?

Update:
My problem is that I have a webservice that stores an item. Item has fields and is declared as:

```
class Item {
    IField[] fields{get;set;}

    more properties and methods
}
```

Comment: A straight forward solution would be to pass another parameter that will indicate the actual type of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The answer is no](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/376527-webmethod-returning-interface-receiving-interface-parameter). If you are able to, try an abstract base class instead of an interface - that should serialize correctly, and may be suitable for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should visit this topic too, [Web Service Can't Serialize an Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659039/web-service-cant-serialize-an-interface)